# How to handle promises in mapWith TransformationType? [@nartc/automapper]

Tags: javascript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm currently working on a project using NestJS framework. As it's ORM, I chose the recommended option: TypeORM.

One of my entities that want to map to a custom DTO response is the following:

```
@Entity('careers')
export class Career {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id!: string;

  @Index('name-idx', { unique: true })
  @Column()
  name!: string;

  @AutoMap(() => CareerCourseRelation)
  @OneToMany(() => CareerCourseRelation, (careerCourseRelation) => careerCourseRelation.career)
  careerCourseRelations!: Promise<CareerCourseRelation[]>;
}
```

The corresponding DTO has the following properties:

```
@Exclude()
export class ResponseCareerDto {
  @Expose()
  id!: string;

  @Expose()
  name!: string;

  @Expose()
  @AutoMap(() => ResponseTernaryDto) // <- DTO of CareerCourseRelation
  careerCourseRelations!: ResponseTernaryDto[];
}
```

There's no problem with fields changing its name. However, as I'm using a Promise in Career to have the linked careerCourseRelations entities lazy loaded, the mapper must map from a Promise<CareerCourseRelation[]> to ResponseTernaryDto[].

To help with that, I proceed to implement a custom Profile according to @nartc/automapper docs.

```
@Profile()
export class CareerProfile extends ProfileBase {
  constructor(mapper: AutoMapper) {
    super();
    mapper.createMap(Career, ResponseCareerDto).forMember(
      (dest) => dest.careerCourseRelations,
      mapWith(ResponseTernaryDto, (src) => src.careerCourseRelations),
    );
  }
}
```

Inside the mapWith method is where I find the problem. According to mapWith's signature, the callback ***must*** return the mapped value, in order to continue mapping the nested models. However, the above code doesn't work, due to returning a promise which the callbacks doesn't await.

One possible solution would be to make use of async/await:

```
mapWith(ResponseTernaryDto, async (src) => await src.careerCourseRelations)
```

Nevertheless, we're stuck in the same situation, as now the callback wraps the result in another promise because we used the async keyword.

So, after reading thoroughly @nartc/automapper documentation, I didn't found any way to deal with this particular use case.

**Which will be an easy way to handle promises and get their results to make mapping possible?**

**Note**: I'm using the Transformer Plugin and that's why there's only the necessary @AutoMap decorators where there're needed.

Answer (score 1):

Quick work around would be to use an `afterMap` callback. We're going to focus on the `Profile`

```
@Profile()
export class CareerProfile extends ProfileBase {
  constructor(mapper: AutoMapper) {
    super();
    mapper.createMap(Career, ResponseCareerDto)
      .forMember(
         (dest) => dest.careerCourseRelations,
         ignore() // first, we will ignore it from the mapping operations
       )
      .afterMap(async (source, destination) => { // use afterMap callback here
         const resolvedValues = await source.careerCourseRelations;
         destination.careerCourseRelations = mapper.mapArray(resolvedValues, ResponseTernaryDto, CareerCourseRelation);
      });
  }
}
```

However, since `afterMap` is now an async callback, it will run at the end of the current Event Loop, you will need to use the `mapAsync` version of `AutoMapper`.

```
// before
this.mapper.map(career, ResponseCareerDto, Career);

// after
await this.mapper.mapAsync(career, ResponseCareerDto, Career);
```

Comment: Yes, it seems to have done the trick. Follow up of the original problem [here](https://github.com/nartc/mapper/issues/185)

Answer (score 0):

Im my case, I decide to turn on eager loading, considering this thread on git hub: https://github.com/nartc/mapper/issues/185#issuecomment-1193160738.
Because we are going to load the relation anyway on the dto, lazy loading dont make sense anymore im my opinion,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).